# Detecting a pattern in a time series with a Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I new to working with Neural Networks and I want to detect a pattern in a time series and return some measure of the certainty/uncertainty when a pattern has been detected:

```
data={1, 2.5, 1, 1.9, 0.10388, 0.7235, 0.8979, 0.97703, 0.151623, 0.319143, 1.2, \
2, 0.4068, 0.816, 0.470704, 0.072562, 0.313688, 0.7371, 0.19443, 1, \
2.1, 1.3, 1.5, 2, 0.243, 0.342, 0.8473, 0.18084, 0.63023, 0.889836, 0.3149, 0.8273, \
0.72881, 0.55363, 0.38214, 1, 2, 1, 0.672, 0.533, 0.69, 0.24837, 0.607, \
0.9488, 1, 2.7, 0.9, 2.2, 0.39696, 0.41164, 0.0979}
```

In this exemplary time series, the pattern I want to detect is `1,2,1,2`. But the pattern in the time series is confounded by noise.

Working with `Classify` does not seem to work, since it only accepts at least two classes. So I'm having trouble finding the right function for this and hope for some help.

Comment: Way too small data for "detecting a pattern" with a neural network.

Comment: Yes of course! This is just an exemplary time series in order to clarify what I mean. The "real" data I want to apply it to has enough data points for training and testing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define pattern and level of noise:

```
pattern = {1, 2, 1, 2};
d = .01;
```

This makes a sample of time series with 50 points:

```
sample:=Flatten[Insert[
    MeanFilter[RandomReal[2.5,46],1],
    pattern + d RandomReal[{-1,1},4],
    RandomInteger[{1,46}]]];
```

The pattern is randomly inserted in data smoothed out with `MeanFilter`. Your pattern is in orange frame:

```
ListStepPlot[sample, AspectRatio -> 1/7, ImageSize -> Full, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

### Method 1: no machine learning

If you need position of your pattern inside time series relaxing with respect given noise level, you do not need machine learning. Here is how to do it:

```
SequencePosition[sample,
{x_/;1-d<x<1+d,y_/;2-d<y<2+d,
z_/;1-d<z<1+d,w_/;2-d<w<2+d}]
```

> {{21, 24}}

### Method 2: predicting position

To predict position of pattern inside the series you need `Predict`. First define a function that finds starting index of pattern exactly:

```
datapos[data_]:=SequencePosition[data,
{x_/;1-d<x<1+d,y_/;2-d<y<2+d, 
z_/;1-d<z<1+d,w_/;2-d<w<2+d}][[1,1]]
```

Build training set of 10,000 samples:

```
trainingset = # -> datapos[#] & /@ Table[sample, 10000];
```

Train with quality:

```
p = Predict[trainingset, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]

PredictorInformation[p]
```

[image]

Compare exact and learned methods:

```
In[]:= {datapos[#],p[#]}&@(tmp=sample)
Out[]= {22,20.851}
```

See distribution:

```
Plot[Evaluate@PDF[p[tmp, "Distribution"], x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Build test set and measurements:

```
testset = # -> datapos[#] & /@ Table[sample, 100];
pm = PredictorMeasurements[p, testset]
```

Measure some stats:

```
In[]:= pm[ "StandardDeviation"]
Out[]= 1.50146

pm["ComparisonPlot"]
```

[image]

### Method 3: testing time series on presence of pattern

On the other hand if you have many time series samples which you need to test on the presence of the pattern (TRUE/FALSE) - you can use `Classify`,  as you have 2 classes exactly. You can do the same steps below with a neural net too, but `Classify` will keep this simple.

Build a training set out of 10,000 samples the more the better:

```
trainingset = <|"TRUE" -> Table[sample, 5000], 
   "FALSE" -> Table[MeanFilter[RandomReal[2.5, 50], 1], 5000]|>;
```

Train with quality:

```
c = Classify[trainingset, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

This is typical work of the classifier - pattern detected successfully with given probabilities:

```
In[]:= c[sample, "Probabilities"]
Out[]= <|"FALSE" -> 0.188043, "TRUE" -> 0.811957|>
```

Build test set:

```
testset = <|"TRUE" -> Table[sample, 100], 
   "FALSE" -> Table[MeanFilter[RandomReal[2.5, 50], 1], 100]|>;
```

Build measurements:

```
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[c, testset]
```

Good accuracy:

```
In[]:= cm["Accuracy"]
Out[]= 0.98
```

which can also be checked as:

```
cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

My WL version:

```
In[]:= $Version
Out[]= 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)
```

Comment: Thank you Vitaliy, this gives me a lot of information to get deeper into this topic, awesome :)!

Comment: How do you find the location of the pattern using the third method?